# How to redirect to another page if slug dynamically change in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i have a page where there is a permanent slug and another page where slug is keep on changing. i want to redirect user if he is not logged in.

i am using this:-

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

   if ( (is_page( array( 'administration', 'documents', 'images' )) && ! is_user_logged_in()) ) {

      wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/log-in/', 301 ); 
      exit;
   }
}
```

This is working if it has permanent slug as in if condition but how can i redirect user if page URL is like http://siteurl/portfolio/this-is-image-5/ where `this-is-image-5` is keep on changing based on portfolio posts. so it can be `this-is-image-6`, `this-is-image-7` and so on. So please tell me how to redirect based on this dynamic slug for non-logged in user.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current post type and then redirect. Check this code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );
function redirect_to_specific_page() {
   global $post;
   if ( ($post->post_type == 'portfolio') && ! is_user_logged_in()) ) {
      wp_redirect( get_site_url().'/log-in/', 301 ); 
      exit;
   }
}
```